# How to use bubblesort with instances

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

Good evening guys,

for my homework i have to implement a class called 'car' which consists of certain parameters like 'registration', 'color', 'manufacturer', 'model' with with output and comparison methods. 
After this i have to implement a bubble sort to sort these instances by 'manufacturer' and 'model'; the other attributes are neglectable.

my Code so far:

```
def class car():
    self.__init__(self, registration, color, manufacturer, model):
        self.registration = registration
        self.color = color
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
    def output(self):
        return '{}{}{}{}'.format(self.registration, self.color, self. manufacturer, self.model)

    def bubblesort(list_1):
        for k in range(len(list_1)-1, 0, -1):
            for i in range(0,k):
                if list_1[i] >  list[i+1]:
                    list_1[i], list_1[i+1] = list_1[i+1], list_1[i]
        return list_1
```

what i have to do now is two create an instance of car like this:

```
instance = [Car(2003, 'black', 'BMW', 'M4')
            Car(2005, 'red', 'Audi', 'Q3')
            Car(2010, 'green', 'BMW', 'X1')
            Car(2007, 'pink', 'Subaru', 'BRZ')]
            Car(1998, 'black', 'Audi', 'Q5')
```

and after sorting it has to look like this:

```
[Car(2005, 'red', 'Audi', 'Q3')
Car(1998, 'black', 'Audi', 'Q5')
Car(2003, 'black', 'BMW', 'M4')
Car(2010, 'green', 'BMW', 'X1')
Car(2007, 'pink', 'Subaru', 'BRZ')]
```

So I have pretty much everything but i don't know how to sort 'the whole instance' - actually i don't even know if you can say this...:D

Maybe some of you guys can help me out; thanks.

Comment: oh, sry - passed the wrong argument in bubblesort! actually it is called bubblesort(list_1) - i'll edit it; thanks!

Comment: so actually list_1 is instance which contains the list of instances - you know what i mean? I'm quite new to OOP so excuse my bad wording :/

Comment: this code is not valid Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code that does what you need. The comparison operator is overloaded (I guessed the logic of comparison).

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, registration, color, manufacturer, model):
        self.registration = registration
        self.color = color
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format(self.registration, self.color, self. manufacturer, self.model)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Car):
            if self.manufacturer != other.manufacturer:
                return self.manufacturer.lower() > other.manufacturer.lower()
            else:
                return self.model.lower() > other.model.lower()

def bubblesort(list_1):
    for k in range(len(list_1)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(0,k):
            if list_1[i] >  list_1[i+1]:
                list_1[i], list_1[i+1] = list_1[i+1], list_1[i]
    return list_1

instance = [Car(2003, 'black', 'BMW', 'M4'),
            Car(2005, 'red', 'Audi', 'Q3'),
            Car(2010, 'green', 'BMW', 'X1'),
            Car(2007, 'pink', 'Subaru', 'BRZ'),
            Car(1998, 'black', 'Audi', 'Q5')]

sorted_instance = bubblesort(instance)
for item in sorted_instance:
    print(str(item))
```

Comment: You can simplify the logic of `__eq__` down to `return (self.manufacturer.lower(), self.model.lower()) == (other.manufacturer.lower(), other.model.lower())`. Same applies to `__gt__`, you only need to replace `==` with `>`, and the tuple class does the rest, the way you described

Comment: ooooh my gosh - thank you very much; I appreciate it! 
Would it be possible for you to explain how the __gt__ method works? 
Would be nice to know so I can use it from now on :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whenever Python interpreter stumbles across comparison operator - ">" ("greater than") __gt__ function is executed for instance that is left value of the operator (here list_1[i]) . Right value (here list_1[i+1]) of the operator is "other" argument.

Comment: okay - then..what exactly is the difference between __str__ function and __repr__ function? is it just 'easier to read' than __repr__ or is there any information loss by using __str__ ?

Comment: Here is quite decent explanation if u want to delve deeper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can only sort comparable things, that is, something that can be thought of "less than" another such thing.

For cars it might be model name, year, etc, or a combination of these.

To make an object comparable, you need to implement methods like `__lt__` (less tan) and `__eq__` (equals).

But your class seems to be just a bunch of immutable fields (which is usually good). Try using a `namedtuple`, it creates a class for you, and it provides an implementation for comparison methods. With it, your cars would be sorted by the first field declared, then by second, etc.

Also, the `bubblesort` method definitely does not belong to the `Car` class, for it never uses any instance data of a car. It should be a standalone function.

Comment: see, that's why I like this platform so much! unfortunately I do not know how to implement everything at all..thanks for your advice - I'll try and see if i get things running :)